# Read contacts individually from each sim card in a dual sim phone

Tags: android, android-contacts, dual-sim

Currently I am using SubscriptionManager class api to detect whether sim is present/absent.
In single sim phone below method worked to read contact from sim card.

```
   Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn/");
    ContentResolver mContentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = mContentResolver.query(simUri, null, null, null, null);
```

my application is an system app and have a rooted device.
For Dual sim phone how to read contacts from each sim card individually.

If anyone can think of some other ways, they are most welcome. I would really appreciate any kind of help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ACCOUNT_TYPE field of the ContactsContract API to find SIM contacts.

You'll need to query over the RawContacts table, to get a list of all RawContacts that are stored on the SIM card, and get the contact ids from that list.

```
String selection = RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "='vnd.sec.contact.sim'";
Cursor cur = mContentResolver.query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, null);
// cur should now contain all the requested contacts
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cur);
```

**UPDATE**

Since this didn't work, it means the values stored for the `ACCOUNT_TYPE` are not as expected, possibly something like `vnd.sec.contact.sim1` and `vnd.sec.contact.sim2`.

You can create a test method to print all values of `ACCOUNT_TYPE`s from all contacts, and use that output to figure out the correct values you need.

```
HashSet<String> accountTypes = new HashSet<String>();
String[] projection = new String[] { RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE };
Cursor cur = mContentResolver.query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
if (cur != null) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        accountTypes.add(cur.getString(0));
    }
}
for (String type : accountTypes) {
    Log.d("ACCOUNT_TYPE", type);
}
// Check the output in LogCat and look for `ACCOUNT_TYPE`s that look like `sim` types. then add those values to the selection of the above method
```

Comment: I am getting following exception android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT sort_key, send_to_voicemail, pinned, sec_custom_alert, display_name, display_name_alt AS phonetic_name_style FROM view_raw_contacts_restricted WHERE (1) AND ((account_type=vnd.sec.contact.sim))

Comment: yeah, i was missing an apostrophe around the selection value, fixed now

Comment: I tried your solution but no luck.                           
selection = account_type='vnd.sec.contact.sim'
cur = android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@15ebf227
I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@15ebf227
I/System.out: <<<<<

Comment: @marmor i have same issue i want create contact programtically  in dual sim but i dont know how to differ content URI for that can u please suggest me